# How to trigger jenkins job that execute automation test scripts when code is pushed in development server?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Jenkins. I have development code repository at bitbucket and another test script code repository at bitbucket. Now I have setup a Jenkins job by linking test code repository. Is there any way to trigger a build when code is pushed in develop repo?

I tried many times by pushing change in develop repo, but it does not triggers the jenkins job.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Jenkins trigger as an SCM poll. 
You will have to enter a cron expression for the polling time period, like:

```
*/5 * * * *
```

This means polling from 5 to 5 minutes. If any change is detected, then the build is triggered.

Comment: For this, do i need to add both (dev and test scripts) git repo URL in source code management ?

Comment: You just need to have the jenkins git-plugin and git-client-plugin in the jenkins instance, configure the URL, and make sure your repository URL has .git at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the BitBucket Plugin to your Jenkins instance. It will allow you to configure a webhook in BitBucket that will then trigger any Jenkins job listening for that webhook. The plugin's page has a detailed breakdown, but the basics are;

In your repo in BitBucket, create a new Webhook using your Jenkins' url. I believe the url is generally `http://[your jenkins url]/bitbucket-hook/`
Make the trigger a repo push.
In your Jenkins job, check the box "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" under the Build Triggers section.
Now any time you commit to the repo you created the Webhook on, that Jenkins job will be run.

You can also limit what branches trigger commits by parameterizing your Jenkins build to ignore certain branches / keywords / etc if that's something you need for your specific project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use webhooks to trigger build automatically. There are few options how to use it. See the following articles: [this](https://medium.com/@mohan08p/jenkins-integration-with-bitbucket-github-webhook-25a191507cab), [this](https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/381419546/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket+Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin) and [this](https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/381288449/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket+Git+Plugin).